# Incorrect spacing when filtering by [.net] tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface, question-lists

SO looks fine when you're filtering by some tags ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+linq)):

[image: correct spacing]

Bun not once the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag is added to the query ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+linq+or+.net)):

[image: incorrect spacing]

Comment: Yeah, it seems to add in space for the advertisement/sponsorship.

Comment: We are aware of this and are looking into it. Appears to only effect the [tag:.net] tag. So, not 2/3 tags, but that specific one.

Comment: @Oded huh, you're right. It is solely dependent on the .net tag. I'll update my question to reflect that

Comment: Looks a-OK now.

Comment: @Oded Um, I'm actually seeing the exact same sponsored links in [tag:.net] and in [tag:azure]. Is this right, or is it somehow showing the wrong links?

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Question for our sales team, but I think so. Go Microsoft ;)

Comment: @Oded Okay, thanks. It's still showing up a little weird in the list, see my [followup question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195621/weird-border-issue-around-sponsored-links) for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag has been sponsored recently, but our ad network CDN hasn't caught up with the uploaded assets yet, causing this issue.

Once the CDN catches up, this will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The place you are refering to is an advertisement space, where the ads appear. Here is the example

[image: ad]

I just visited the link you provided, and found that there was an ad.

The issue there might be an Internet connectivity issue, so the loading of the ad got stopped or a `500`. I am not sure, what was the main issue! But the issue is something like that.