# Weird border issue around sponsored links

Tags: bug, design, question-lists, sponsored-tags

When filtering by multiple tags, the tag wiki doesn't appear, but the sponsored links are still there. This can cause some weird formatting issues:

[image: Normal colors]

It may be hard to see exactly what I mean, so I've modified the border and background colors for demonstration purposes:

[image: Modified colors]

- The border around the sponsored links seems to be two pixels too narrow on the right side. This actually occurs regardless of whether or not the tag wiki link appears.
- The whole border hangs down five pixels into the space of the question below it. This is only noticeable when the question is highlighted (as in my example).

Comment: Wait - we have sponsored links?

Comment: @und - Adblock much? :P

Comment: @Lix Huh - I guess adblock does get them. I wouldn't have thought it would be that smart.

Comment: @Undo - Those are served via adzerk... so... yeah.

Comment: @Oded Why not an in-house system? I'd kind of like to see them.

Comment: @Undo Why not just disable AdBlock on SO then?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I can't reproduce this on win 7 / latest chrome. What browser / OS are you using?

Comment: @KorneelBouman Actually, it appears to be fixed now; I'm no longer able to reproduce it. If you want to post an answer indicating that it's been fixed sometime in the past week, I'll accept that.